# Json sample webservice URL

Tags: jquery, json, image, web-services, gallery

I am trying to make an image gallery using jquery and html5. I am working on the frontend. Could any one of you suggest a json webservice  which returns json object(with imageURL)?

Thanks

Comment: Returns them from where?

Comment: What is the URL format for JSON? AFAIK JSON has no URL datatype. It has strings and strings have no imposed format.

Comment: http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=216.113.168.141 - I meant something like this

Comment: Do you mean you want a web service that returns a JSON object containing multiple elements of information about an image? Such as URL, thumbnail-URL, title, alt, description etc.?

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/KM5Mq/) ?

Comment: MihaiStancu - Yes exactly. Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample [twitter](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json) response